# Can't get `Spinner` option to work (jQuery UI tabs)

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

According to http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs, tabs that load content via AJAX will show "Loading..." while the content loads. If you want to customize this message, you can (supposedly) set the `spinner` option:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ spinner: "Just a sec..."});
```

However, I'm having these problems:

- Setting the `spinner` option doesn't seem to work
- Even when I don't set the `spinner` option, "Loading..." doesn't appear
- "Loading..." doesn't appear for me on the "Content via Ajax" demo on http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer (http://osdir.com/ml/jquery-ui/2009-04/msg00769.html) -- the contents of the tab need to be enclosed in a `<span>`:

```
<li><a href="http://url">will not work</a></li>

<li><a href="http://url"><span>WILL work</span></a></li>
```

Needless to say, it's pretty insane that this is:

- Not documented anywhere
- Incorrect on the *example page*

Comment: Thanks for posting that. Had been looking for the same thing!